# Combining elements in a Java stream

Tags: java

I have a list with a flow of elements of type H(eader), I(tem) and C(loser). They are coming in the following order; H, I, I, C, H, I, C and so on.
I want to combine sets to new elements of type HIC, HIIC, HIIIC, and so on. Is there a way I can do this in a Java stream like:

```
producer().combine(...).
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own `Collector` in order to do something bespoke like this.

There are three steps to a `Collector`:

- Initialise an accumulator (a `List` of HICs in your case)
- Add each element to your accumulator (so a different action based on whether it's a header, item or closer)
- Convert your accumulator to a final result, if appropriate.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html